# Apple push notification is not working in production certificate

Tags: iphone, xcode, notifications

I have followed :  [tutorial-part-12](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-) .It works in development certificate but it do not work in production certificate.

I already changed sandbox to  `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195` in my php.

I created production.pem with this steps.

```
$ openssl x509 -in aps_developer_identity.cer -inform der 
    -out PushChatCert.pem

$ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushChatKey.pem -in PushChatKey.p12
```

Enter Import Password: 
MAC verified OK
Enter PEM pass phrase: 
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:

```
$ cat PushChatCert.pem PushChatKey.pem > ck.pem
```

and I uploade my ck.pem to my shared host. 
It is nothing errors but it does not push notification.

in my php ,it said : *Connected to APNS Message successfully delivered*

Comment: Have you built and deployed your app using the ad-hoc distribution certificate rather than your developer certificate?

Comment: @NickBull You should post that as an answer. :)

Comment: @SimonGermain I was going to, but there was insufficient information to determine if the OP had tried that in which case it isn't really an answer, but a comment. But what the heck - I've put it as an answer now :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to build and sign your app using the ad-hoc distribution certificate rather than with the developer certificate when using the "live" servers rather than the sandbox servers.

Comment: Did you mean Production Push SSL Certificate in App Ids? I already used it.

Comment: It said Connected to APNS Message successfully delivered .Did it mean my shared host supports apple push notification?

Comment: No, I mean the ad-hoc distribution certificate for signing the build of the app that you are putting on your test devices. If you sign with the developer certificate, then you can only use the sandbox push servers. Sign it with the ad-hoc for using the live servers. The message may have been delivered to the server, but if your app isn't registering against the server with the ad-hoc certificate in it, then it will never receive the notification

Comment: Have a look at the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile.html)

Comment: I see Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile. I use app store Provisioning Profile.Does it push notification?

Comment: my server is linux.Do I have to use http://www.entrust.net or http://urbanairship.com/pricing ?

Comment: What have you done for this dear because i am stuck on the same issue.